# C# Web Services Routing Controller to Defined URL

Tags: c#, rest, controller, owin

I am new to C#, committing to a little Spike. I have built a few POCO OWIN self-hosting services and am trying to create a controller but guides and documentation everywhere appear to be pointing me in the incorrect direction.

I am adding default mapping to a configuration method inside a startup class. Then in my controller I have a simple GET method. This works like a charm, when I send a request to it using the url defined in my startup routing the method gets invoked. But now I need to set up a second method to be invoked by a new url.

I don't understand what I am missing and what I am not understanding but everything I attempt does not work for me:

relevant code in the controller:

```
// GET api/ManagedService
    public string[] Get()
    {
        Start();
        return new string[]
        {
            "Job Processed."
        };
    }
```

Relevant code in my startup class:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.EnableCors();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/start"
        );
```

So on visiting api/{controller}/start I invoke my get but I want to invoke a different method with api/{controller}/receiptandsend.

Comment: Everything that I find addresses a structure to manipulate or view a single object I.e., api/controller/, api/controller/5, api/controller/delete.... but this isn't what I need. I need something similar to @RequestMapping in the Javasphere

Comment: You can try doing attribute routing: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what the problem is but try to change your routeTemplate to "api/{controller}/{action}" instead. The routeTemplate you are using assumes that you have an action (method) called start on every controller. Alternatively you could try to add another route, something like name: "anotherOne", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/receiptandsend" but I don't think that is really the way to do it correctly.

edit: By the way, your Get method should probably be named something else, like StartJob or something, "Get" seems a bit misleading seeing that you don't get anything back except a text saying that you started some other process.

Comment: So to better understand, if I use {action} it will run the method named accordingly?

Comment: when I try this I am getting a 405 which is positive as at least it recognises its is a thing so where am I wrong? This should be something so simple and I can getting increasingly annoyed with myself.

Comment: Ok, so it does work, I was using a browser making PUT requests. Positing with Postman and my rest interface is working. Thank you for this @grom.

Comment: No problem! 
The point is that when you set up the route you are saying what pattern the URL has to have for your application to accept it. 
{controller} and {action} means "any controller name" or "any action name", but when you wrote api/{controller}/start you were telling your app to only accept URL:s that has the form of "api/{any controller name}/start". And so sending "api/test/receiptandsend" caused your app to refuse because there was no route accepting an action called "receiptandsend".

Hope that helps :)